# First half of query works but the tail-end doesnt

Tags: php, sorting

I have posted this before but was unable to explain with clarity so reposting.

I have this query i am using.  I need to sort it by $variis, but it seems the sort is not working. I double checked field names and tables. The query works but it won't sort it by the $variis.  I have also tried using the parentheses around help_box.status, but it doesn't work.

Code:

```
//Unseen
$variis = "Need Help";
$myid = <the user id>;

$sql = "select car_help.car_id, agent_names.agent_name, help_box.status, 
car_help.why_car, car_help.date_time_added, car_help.just_date, 
car_help.type, agent_names.agent_id
from car_help LEFT JOIN agent_names on car_help.agent_whois = agent_names.agent_id 
LEFT JOIN help_box on car_help.somefield= help_box.somefield
where agent_names.system_id = '$myid' and car_help.system_id='$myid' 
and added_by <> '$myid' and help_box.status = '$variis'
UNION
select magazine_help.note_id, agent_names.agent_name, help_box.status, 
magazine_help.note_name, magazine_help.date_time_added, 
magazine_help.just_date, magazine_help.type, agent_names.agent_id
from magazine_help LEFT JOIN agent_names on 
magazine_help.agent_id = agent_names.agent_id 
LEFT JOIN help_box on car_help.somefield= help_box.somefield 
where agent_names.system_id='$myid' and 
magazine_help.system_id = '$myid' and added_by <> '$myid' 
and help_box.status = '$variis'
UNION
select motorcycle_help.rand_id, agent_names.agent_name, 
help_box.status, motorcycle_help.rand_name, motorcycle_help.date_time_added,     
motorcycle_help.just_date, motorcycle_help.type, agent_names.agent_id
from motorcycle_help LEFT JOIN agent_names ON 
motorcycle_help.by_who = agent_names.agent_id
LEFT JOIN help_box on car_help.somefield= help_box.somefield
where agent_names.system_id = '$myid' and 
motorcycle_help.system_id='$myid' and added_by <> '$myid' 
and help_box.status = '$variis'
UNION
select mobile_questions.bal_test_id, agent_names.agent_name, 
help_box.status, mobile_questions.bal_why, mobile_questions.date_time_added,   
mobile_questions.just_date, mobile_questions.type, agent_names.agent_id
from mobile_questions LEFT JOIN agent_names ON 
mobile_questions.agent_who_ordered = agent_names.agent_id
LEFT JOIN help_box on car_help.somefield= help_box.somefield
where agent_names.system_id = '$myid' and 
mobile_questions.system_id='$myid' and added_by <> '$myid' 
and help_box.status = '$variis'
ORDER BY date_time_added DESC LIMIT $startrow, 20";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());


if ($result == "")
{
echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
print("");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$row1 = $row['row_name'];


print("$row1");
}

}
```

Comment: That is a massive query. Can you perhaps explain your table structure a bit more, and what you're ultimately trying to retrieve from your database?

Comment: add *(* before first select and *)* before order by; then its  "order by status ..."

Comment: @josh i am doing the sort by using help_box.status to show only results where status equals need help...

Comment: @dagon i tried that already.  doesn't work.

Comment: it's the correct syntax for sorting a union. post what you tried

Comment: bad me, bracket around each select then ORDER BY .. outside at the end.

Comment: Perhaps I should have read the comments. I have posted the comment by @Dagon as an answer. Anyway he is right. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: @phil i checked everything.  besides the query is working its just not showming me the particular rows i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the result set, you need to put parentheses before the first select and at the end of the last select, and then put the order by statement after the closing parantheses.

However I do not quite understand your question.  You way you want to sort by $variis, but you are selecting on that value.

UPDATE:

If you are not getting rows you expect, then the selection may be too strict. Try using LIKE instead of '=', or even use wildcards.

Comment: yes, you see $variis equals "Need help"  So i only want those results that show "need help" to show not anything else.

Comment: So you want to select on $variis, not order by it. It should work with the where clause in each select. What are you getting?